# Permissions to edit jobs without sysadmin rights

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

NT group (created for developers) has login with the `Sysadmin` role on the Prod server to be able to execute, update, create, etc … SQL Server Agent jobs, run SSIS packages etc.

New requirements, that developers should not be sysadmin and not to be able to see some sensitive data.

What was done:

- Login (for NT Group) – `[dmn\group_name_dev_in_prod]`
- `[dmn\group_name_dev_in_prod]` was added to SSISDB as user and into ssis_admin role
- `[dmn\group_name_dev_in_prod]` was added to msdb As user and into SQLAgentOperatorRole and also db_owner
- `[dmn\group_name_dev_in_prod]` was added to every database used in their deployments with necessary rights
- Proxy created and `SQLAgentOperatorRole` added to it

Now members of the group, can start any jobs, create any jobs, execute any jobs, but they cannot update/create existing steps.

The owner of all the jobs is sa. I cannot make `[dmn\group_name_dev_in_prod]` the jobs owner as its an NT group.

Is there way around it?

Comment: This cannot be done without sysadmin permissions, per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-update-jobstep-transact-sql#Permissions). That said, any permission restriction in SQL Server can always be worked around by dedicating a stored procedure to the job, and using `EXECUTE AS` (quick and dirty) or signing with a certificate (slow and clean), combined with granting users permission to execute the procedure. Of course this will mean users cannot use the SSMS interface to do it, but it's something.

Comment: Note that there is a really good reason for the sysadmin requirement that you should be aware of before making this possible: if a job is executed under different credentials, the ability to change a job step is a really simple way to mount a privilege escalation attack. All a user has to do is find a job executing with sysadmin permissions and update a step to do whatever they please as sysadmin (including reading sensitive data); this is why a custom stored procedure would still have to check that nothing of that sort is attempted.